# Python socket receive - hanging in While-loop due to extremely long received message length

Tags: python, sockets, struct, tcp

I have the following code for server and client to send live video streams:

### Server

```
...
TCP_IP= TCP_IP_LOCAL
TCP_PORT=8093
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(1)
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ret, enc_fram = cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame)
    data = pickle.dumps(enc_fram)
    print("length is: " + len(data))
    s.sendall(struct.pack("L",len(data)) + data)
```

Printout gives:

```
length is: 93800
length is: 95323
length is: 95519
length is: 95602
...
```

### Client

```
data=""
payload_size=struct.calcsize("L")

while True:
    print('1) len(data)=  %s  payload_size= %s ' %(str(len(data)), str(payload_size)))
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data_par = conn.recv(4096)
        data += data_par
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("L",packed_msg_size)[0]

    print('2) msg_size = %s' %(str(msg_size)))
    while len(data) < msg_size:
            data += conn.recv(4096)
```

Printout gives:

```
1) len(data)=  0  payload_size= 8
2) msg_size = 7887331693890203240
```

Due to the long msg_size the Client is stuck in the second while loop.

In general the code should be ok. If the server is running on Laptop1, it works fine.
If server is running on Laptop2 I have the problem with the long message size.
Could it be related to different packages which might be installed on the server host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't start your `struct` format string with a specifier character, the byte ordering and field sizes are the native values for each system - which don't necessarily agree with each other!  You appear to be moving data from a system where the native `"L"` format is 4 bytes, to one where it is 8 bytes, so the first 4 bytes of your payload are being misinterpreted as part of the length.  Use a format like `"<L"` instead, and you get a standardized layout of the data, which is the same on all systems.